# How to align expressions between alignment regex in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have the following two lines in Sublime Text 3:

```
Rectangle(Maxwell, "MagnetsWEstart" , "r_ta - h_pm",  42,"NdFe35", True, "WE")
Rectangle(Maxwell, "MagnetsWEend", "r_ta", 1984.42, "NdFe35",False, "WE")
```

And I'd like to **align all commata** and the preceding text to the right:

```
Rectangle(Maxwell, "MagnetsWEstart", "r_ta - h_pm",      42, "NdFe35",  True, "WE")
Rectangle(Maxwell,   "MagnetsWEend",        "r_ta", 1984.42, "NdFe35", False, "WE")
```

I downloaded the [**Align Tab**](https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab) package and created the key-binding

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "align_tab", "args" : {"user_input" : ","} }
```

The result is already close to what I want:

```
Rectangle(Maxwell , "MagnetsWEstart" , "r_ta - h_pm" , 42      , "NdFe35" , True  , "WE")
Rectangle(Maxwell , "MagnetsWEend"   , "r_ta"        , 1984.42 , "NdFe35" , False , "WE")
```

But how can I align the expressions between the commata to the right and also get red of the added space before the commas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps inspired by [**ndn's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32074426/2605073) were finally leading to the desired result:

1)  Install [**reg_replace**](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace) and [**Align tab**](https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab) package

2)  Package: Reg_Replace -> Settings -> User:

```
{
    "replacements": {
        "commaRightRegex": {
            "find": "(\\s,)",
            "replace": ",",
            "greedy": true,
            "case": false
        }
    },
    "selection_only": true,
}
```

3)  Tools -> New Plugin -> Include [**run_multiple.py**](https://gist.github.com/nilium/3327730)

4)  Key Bindings -> User -> add:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"],
    "command": "run_multiple_commands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {"command": "align_tab", "args" : {"user_input" : ",/r"}},
            {"command": "reg_replace", "args": {"replacements": ["commaRightRegex"]}}
        ]
    }
}
```

Which will finally enable the desired output with a single keyboard shortcut:

```
Rectangle(Maxwell, "MagnetsWEstart", "r_ta - h_pm",      42, "NdFe35",  True, "WE")
Rectangle(Maxwell,   "MagnetsWEend",        "r_ta", 1984.42, "NdFe35", False, "WE")
```

Answer (score 1):

After aligning with Align Tab, match

```
[(,] *\K(.+?)( +)(?=,)
```

Replace with `\2\1`

Comment: With find&replace (regex mode) I got no matches. Unfortunately I don't understand enough of regular expressions to find the mistake. And it would just remove the comma, wouldn't it?

Comment: @thewaywewalk, this should be done after getting the result from Align tab that you showed in the last two lines of your question. It will just take the spaces after the words and place them in front of the words.

Comment: yes, I ran your regex on the last two lines in my question and got no matches. Have you tried it in Sublime? Maybe there is something Sublime specific to consider?

Comment: @thewaywewalk, this is very strange, I got 10 matches. Are you sure regex matching is turned on in your search box?

Comment: Btw I updated the regex, there was a small problem because *"r_ta - h_pm"* has spaces.

Comment: Hmm now it works, I will try to find a way to put everything in one macro now, I'd include it in your answer then, if you don't mind?

Comment: @thewaywewalk, fine with me.

Comment: @thewaywewalk, what do you mean. Again, it works with me. What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution. It turns out, Align tab has a built in option that you can add in your regex. Just align by regex and type `,/r`. This means *justify right*.

Comment: This is a nice compromise, does't solve the additonal comma, but I'd rather use this.

Comment: @thewaywewalk, additional comma? Did you mean additional space?

Comment: yes, the `,/r` adds a space before the comma. But don't worry I can live with that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @thewaywewalk, you can match with ` (?=,)` and replace with empty string. :)

Comment: I really don't know why I don't get matches for you suggestions, however find `"find": "(\\s,)",` and `"replace": ",",` finally did the trick in reg_replace.